# Why the LINQ method `Where` in my code is wrong for string[]?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

.Net 3.5

I do the simple LINQ operation:

```
using System.Linq;
...
/* extract product key. I.e. to get the "ACAD-7001:
 * 409" from "SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R17.2\ACAD-
 * 7001:409". Ignore the last '\' char if it 
 * exists. */
string product_code = subkey_name.Split('\\').Where
    (n -> n != string.Empty).Last();
```

But I get the compilation error:

[image]

Hm... But in my code I already use this LINQ-method `Where`.  Whot is wrong?

Comment: Change `(n -> n != string.Empty)` to `(n => n != string.Empty)` (`->` to `=>`)

Comment: Oh... Thank you, I didn't note this misprint.

Comment: Change the -> to => and eplace Where(expression).Last() with Last(expression) although it's not an error. But the error you are getting seems to be different from the problem with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Where
    (n -> n != string.Empty)
```

use

```
Where
    (n => n != string.Empty)
```

(so replace `->` with `=>` which is the correct syntax)

But i'd prefer this:

```
.Where(n => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(n))
```

Comment: I thought about it, but in my case `null` is inpossible, therefore I used `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

changed -> to => and it works

```
string subkey_name = "xyz\\abc\\pqr";

        string product_code = subkey_name.Split('\\').Where(n=>n != string.Empty).Last();
```

output is "pqr"

Use this.

```
string product_code = subkey_name.Split('\\').Last(c=> c != string.Empty);
```